# Context of software timer callback

Tags: multithreading, timer, operating-system, rtos

Considering an OS, generally the Timers are created in advance of Kernel Start. And the timer start is done after the kernel start in some thread. So in the context of which thread does the timer callback gets executed? (is it in the context of the thread from where it was started or from the context of the kernel?

Comment: I think you should execute in kernel context only the callbacks registered by the kernel itself. The other callbacks should be executed in a user thread.

Comment: It's not clear what timers you're talking about. Are you talking about timers set by user-space code? Are you talking about hardware timers? Are you talking about timers the kernel uses for general-purpose timing (like TCP retransmissions)? Are you talking about the timer that ends a timeslice?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  I meant the software timer set by user-space code. What i know is the timer creation  is done before scheduler start and the timer start is done from the user thread. So the doubt here when the TimerStart is called from  the user thread, in which thread's context does the execution of its callback happens..?

Comment: @GinuJacob Oh. Then it completely depends on the nature of the callback. If, for example, a thread is blocked on the timer, then the callback runs in an arbitrary context, sets the thread ready-to-run, and perhaps invokes the scheduler.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So If we consider that we have timer1 whose callback is some simple mathematical operation and timer2 whose callback is waiting for a response from some external entity over a hardware port (ex UART). So in this scenario did you mean the Timer1 callback is executed in the context of the thread on which the timerStart is called and Timer2 callback is executed in the context of an arbitrary thread..?

Comment: @GinuJacob Right. The Timer2 callback may just schedule a "bottom half" to run in a different context though. And the Timer1 likely will be dispatched through a handler that runs in a different context too. The "low level" handlers run in whatever context they happen to be in (after switching to protected mode and switching stacks). If there's work that needs to be done in some other context, they arrange it to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand, or necessarily agree, with the first two sentences.  The context of timer callbacks is, in general, not the context of the thread that requested the callback.  It may be in the context of a dedicated timer thread that maintains a tree or queue of timer objects/structs or the context of some thread pool thread,  Either way, callbacks requested from user space will happen in user space.

With contraints on thread design, (eg. with a design that must service an input queue in a prompt fashion), it can be arranged for timner callbacks can be called on the thread that requested them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a timer is ultimately triggered by a hardware interrupt. The hardware interrupt typically runs mostly in whatever context it happened to interrupt, typically just switching the CPU into kernel mode and switching to a kernel stack. If we're talking about a higher-level timer that has to run in some specific context, the interrupt handler will, directly or indirectly, arrange for the handler to run in the correct context. For example, it might change a thread's state to ready-to-run and invoke the scheduler.